# noty.js is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just begun using [noty.js](http://needim.github.com/noty/) but whenever I try and do the super basic example under "Creating a noty" I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'noty' of object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} is not a function
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svfZa/4/))

Is this a problem with noty, or is it something on my end?

Comment: @Bubbles He's importing it. It's one of the five resources under "Manage resources (5)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest example would be

```
noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

Instead of your

```
$.noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

Comment: whoops I posted the wrong code, I was just testing it with $. in front but it didn't work either.  Here is the right one, as you have on the top and it doesn't work either http://jsfiddle.net/svfZa/5/

Comment: Just rename the variable as you're overwriting the plugin `noty` with the result of calling `noty(...)`

Comment: interesting, that's how it is in the example.  Good eye, thanks for the help!